# How does the compiler decide between const reference and rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

This C++ code:

```
void f(int& i) {
    cout << "by reference" << endl;
}

void f(const int& i) {
    cout << "by const reference" << endl;
}

void f(int&& i) {
    cout << "by rvalue reference" << endl;
}


int main() {
    int x;
    const int y = 5;

    cout << "f(x): ";
    f(x);

    cout << "f(y): ";
    f(y);

    cout << "f(x+y): ";
    f(x+y);

    cout << "f(move(x)): ";
    f(move(x));

    cout << "f(move(y)): ";
    f(move(y));

    cout << "f(move(x+y)): ";
    f(move(x+y));
}
```

Prints:

```
f(x): by reference
f(y): by const reference
f(x+y): by rvalue reference
f(move(x)): by rvalue reference
f(move(y)): by const reference
f(move(x+y)): by rvalue reference
```

I understand all rows except the fifth one: why does "move(y)" not make the compiler choose the overload of f using rvalue reference? And how can I make the compiler choose this variant?

Answer (score 5):

> why does "move(y)" not make the compiler choose the overload of f using rvalue reference

Because `int &&` is a non-const reference, and the argument is `const`.

> And how can I make the compiler choose this variant?

Either by changing the function parameter to `const int &&` (or by removing `const` from `y`),

But normally you don't want to use a `const` rvalue reference. The whole point of moving is to steal resources from the object that's being moved from. You can't do it if the reference to it is `const`.